# Out of range page requests

Tags: cakephp, paginator, cakephp-2.4

I am a begginer in cakephp, my version is 2.4.3

In document I find  sample code below

```
public function index() {
    try {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //Do something here like redirecting to first or last page.
        //$this->request->params['paging'] will give you required info.
    }
}
```

My question :

1.How to redirect to the last page, is there any way to get the total number of pages?

2.I tried to output $this->request->params['paging'] with debug(),but nothing was displayed, just a null value,Did i do anything wrong?

please help me, thinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paging` data not being available is either a bug, or the documentation is wrong - I'd say it's the former, as it would be kinda redundant to count the records again when the `Paginator` component already did that.

Looking at the responsible code:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.3/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L215

shows that the exception is thrown before the `paging` key is set in the `params` array. So until this is fixed you'll either have to modify the core, or count and calculate again on your own, something like this (may need some tweaking):

```
public function index()
{
    try
    {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
    }
    catch(NotFoundException $e)
    {
        extract($this->Paginator->settings);
        $count = $this->ModelName->find('count', compact('conditions'));
        $pageCount = intval(ceil($count / $limit));
        $this->redirect(array('page' => $pageCount));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On CakePHP 3.4 I have this solution:

```
$page  = (!empty($this->request->query['pagina']) ? $this->request->query['pagina'] : 1);
    $this->paginate = ['page' => $page, 'limit' => '10'];

    try {

        $products = $this->paginate($products);

    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {

        $this->paginate = ['page' => $page-1, 'limit' => '10'];
        $products = $this->paginate($products);

    }
```